# LM317HV power supply with transistor substitution

Tags: power-supply

I would like to try this [LM317HV power supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/408297/lm317hv-power-supply)

I was wondering if I can replace the TIP36C transistors with 2SB817 to the design above?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

All the characteristics of the 2SB817 are better than for the TIP36C, except for one: the maximum current. Since that power supply operates at significantly less current than the maximum, that should not be a problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! On the other hand, I could add a +2 SB817 in parallel (in addition, overall 5 transistors) for better current persistence? If so, that would require other diagram modifications..?

Comment: " could add ..." You could. " that would require other diagram modifications..?" That's a different question. Start a new submission for that question.